# Displaying calendar in jquery ui plugin

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I installed the jquery ui plugin from [here](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui). I followed a simple example on that page, resulting my view file as :

```
<%@ page import="mnm.schedule.*" %> 
<!doctypte html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title><g:message code="User's profile" /></title>
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
<r:require module="jquery-ui"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js">
 $(document).ready(function() 
{ ("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'}); 
}) 
</script>        
</head>
  <body>
  <div role="main" class="content scaffold-create">
  <g:form controller="tasks" action ="test">
  date :  <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
  <g:submitButton name="click" />
  </g:form>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I see my page, I can see the text box, but when I click inside the text box, I can't see the date calendar popping out. Where am making the mistake? I even saw the developer console on my chrome, which doesn't throw any error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't that import jquery-xxx.js twice? Both potentially different versions?  Can you post the generated html?

Comment: @tim_yates: I got that output, when I used `g:javascript` tag. I have added it as my answer as well ;)

Comment: Added [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9297045/6509) which explains what the problem was, and how to solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem was that you inlcuded `jquery` here:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
```

And then included jquery here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js">
```

Probably differing versions of jquery, and I guess everything blew up

Changing your `script` tag to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Should solve this...

Comment: Oh! Thanks. You have been always a groovy and grails guy. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: eventhough I got the calendar now, it seems to be so big in size. How can I `Css` it?

Comment: [Roll your own theme and include it via the resources plugin](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/10/grails-goodness-use-different-jquery-ui.html)?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `$` in your code while selecting the datepicker `textbox`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' }); 
});
```

Comment: eventhough that was an error, It doesn't solve my problem. I'm facing the same problem after adding `$`

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the `script` tag , with grails `g:javascript` tag as :

```
<g:javascript>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
          console.log('has been invoked');
        })
</g:javascript>
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker example on the website gives an proper example:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
You can tune your datepicker with some extra functions like:
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'd-m-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: -365,
    maxDate: +0,